# How to make Python Dict from JSON data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: javascript, python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website from which I need certain information. The information I need is the dictionary after `Sw.preloadedData["overview"] =`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sw.preloadedData = {};
    Sw.preloadedData["overview"] = {"Title":"Facebook","Description":"A social utility that connects people, to keep up with friends, upload photos, share links and videos.","GlobalRank":[1,28115594,0],"Country":840,"CountryRanks":{"12":[1,830254,0],"818":[1,463162,0],"604":[1,599566,0],"608":[1,986465,0],"484":[1,1329484,0],"504":[1,672216,0],"862":[1,724854,0],"688":[1,534093,0],"702":[1,427637,0],"703":[1,341310,0],"756":[1,903074,0],"840":[1,5142062,0],"250":[1,1887449,0],"724":[2,1432992,0],"764":[1,857348,0],"76":[1,2733763,0],"784":[1,564929,0],"376":[1,390754,0],"792":[1,979507,0],"804":[8,1073943,1],"344":[1,284415,0],"348":[1,471458,0],"643":[8,1424933,1],"682":[1,692392,0],"380":[1,1441457,0],"392":[3,979893,1],"170":[1,1048409,0],"191":[1,348589,0],"620":[1,841554,0],"642":[1,814441,0],"356":[2,2356839,1],"528":[1,1092022,0],"616":[2,1430485,0],"360":[1,1541560,0],"372":[1,361215,0],"458":[1,851821,0],"36":[1,857177,0],"578":[1,349987,0],"586":[1,553155,0],"704":[2,918752,0],"710":[2,439567,1],"826":[1,2062694,0],"124":[1,1950051,0],"752":[1,577990,0],"300":[1,654931,0],"203":[1,623702,0],"208":[1,350294,0],"32":[1,1223765,0],"100":[1,473283,0],"554":[1,268216,0],"56":[1,1124680,0],"152":[1,725504,0],"156":[25,375144,-1],"158":[1,408462,0],"276":[1,2752131,0],"40":[1,700209,0],"410":[1,327519,0],"246":[1,387528,0]},"Category":"Internet_and_Telecom/Social_Network","CategoryRank":[1,27564,0],"TrafficReach":[0.32364475161620337,0.32385066912312122,0.32476481437213323,0.31948943452696626,0.310612833573507,0.30867420840432391,0.30666509584041279,0.31334128772658171,0.33551546090119239,0.3260064922555041,0.33396164810609369,0.33999592327084549,0.33711315799626795,0.32152719433964483,0.31986157880865085,0.32069766148623413,0.3306823871380894,0.32266565637788247,0.29034777869603251,0.29286953998372667,0.29969130766646174,0.3071060984450904,0.28517166164955293,0.29038329556338477,0.2845053957123595],"TrafficReachStart":1346457600,"TrafficReachEnd":1362096000,"Engagments":[{"Year":2012,"Month":9,"Reach":[0.32364839148251978,0.012621437484750864],"Time":[1225.8536260294338,0.00090266734593069664],"PPV":[21.312597646825566,0.034059623863791355],"Bounce":[0.18813037420762707,0.043481349041723627]},{"Year":2012,"Month":10,"Reach":[0.31325536305080282,-0.032112096661782052],"Time":[1308.5613956266043,0.0674695313053506],"PPV":[25.612224490959978,0.20174109770119109],"Bounce":[0.17672838267013638,-0.060606861520974054]},{"Year":2012,"Month":11,"Reach":[0.33350274816471975,0.064635398151613677],"Time":[1300.8263833937028,-0.0059110808699942563],"PPV":[24.020971463806184,-0.062128653749518592],"Bounce":[0.186024790640559,0.052602801145837264]},{"Year":2012,"Month":12,"Reach":[0.32441610872340648,-0.027246070658540122],"Time":[1331.3137947173564,0.023436956470790138],"PPV":[24.916914500937356,0.03729836815638965],"Bounce":[0.18107629094748873,-0.026601291559208651]},{"Year":2013,"Month":1,"Reach":[0.29998222452228729,-0.075316494909170029],"Time":[1334.5042854365543,0.0023964979044441836],"PPV":[25.52485794831804,0.024398825438752159],"Bounce":[0.18097482510209897,-0.00056034859593612207]},{"Year":2013,"Month":2,"Reach":[0.2842911869016958,-0.052306557982157109],"Time":[1281.8427161473487,-0.039461521303379321],"PPV":[23.201378273544368,-0.091028113828417134],"Bounce":[0.18673378186827794,0.031821866731629678]}],"TrafficSources":{"Search":0.12679771428369516,"Social":0.0095590714393366649,"Mail":0.018352638254343783,"Paid Referrals":0.0010665044954870533,"Direct":0.60148809501325917,"Referrals":0.24273597651387802},"RedirectUrl":"facebook.com"};
    Sw.period = { month:2 ,year:2013,period:6 };
    Sw.siteDomain = "Facebook.com";
    Sw.siteCategory = "Internet_and_Telecom/Social_Network";
    Sw.siteCountry = "840";

</script>
```

If I have the script tag selected with beautifulsoup, how then can I get that (JSON ?) dictionary as a Python Dict?

First I would need to select only that JSON object - **how can I do that?**

And than I would need to translate that JSON object to a Python Dict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do some text processing:

```
import json

scriptline = next((line for line in scripttag.string.splitlines()
    if 'Sw.preloadedData["overview"]' in line))
data = scriptline.split('=', 1)[1].strip(' ;')
data = json.loads(data)
```

The `next(..., '')` call selects the first line that contains `Sw.preloadedData["overview"]`. We then split that line once on `=`, take the rest of the line, remove whitespace and the semicolon, then interpret that as JSON.

This gives me:

```
{u'Category': u'Internet_and_Telecom/Social_Network',
 u'CategoryRank': [1, 27564, 0],
 u'Country': 840,
 u'CountryRanks': {u'100': [1, 473283, 0],
                   u'12': [1, 830254, 0],
                   u'124': [1, 1950051, 0],
                   u'152': [1, 725504, 0],
                   u'156': [25, 375144, -1],
                   u'158': [1, 408462, 0],
                   u'170': [1, 1048409, 0],
                   u'191': [1, 348589, 0],
                   u'203': [1, 623702, 0],
                   u'208': [1, 350294, 0],
                   u'246': [1, 387528, 0],
                   u'250': [1, 1887449, 0],
                   u'276': [1, 2752131, 0],
                   u'300': [1, 654931, 0],
                   u'32': [1, 1223765, 0],
                   u'344': [1, 284415, 0],
                   u'348': [1, 471458, 0],
                   u'356': [2, 2356839, 1],
                   u'36': [1, 857177, 0],
                   u'360': [1, 1541560, 0],
                   u'372': [1, 361215, 0],
                   u'376': [1, 390754, 0],
                   u'380': [1, 1441457, 0],
                   u'392': [3, 979893, 1],
                   u'40': [1, 700209, 0],
                   u'410': [1, 327519, 0],
                   u'458': [1, 851821, 0],
                   u'484': [1, 1329484, 0],
                   u'504': [1, 672216, 0],
                   u'528': [1, 1092022, 0],
                   u'554': [1, 268216, 0],
                   u'56': [1, 1124680, 0],
                   u'578': [1, 349987, 0],
                   u'586': [1, 553155, 0],
                   u'604': [1, 599566, 0],
                   u'608': [1, 986465, 0],
                   u'616': [2, 1430485, 0],
                   u'620': [1, 841554, 0],
                   u'642': [1, 814441, 0],
                   u'643': [8, 1424933, 1],
                   u'682': [1, 692392, 0],
                   u'688': [1, 534093, 0],
                   u'702': [1, 427637, 0],
                   u'703': [1, 341310, 0],
                   u'704': [2, 918752, 0],
                   u'710': [2, 439567, 1],
                   u'724': [2, 1432992, 0],
                   u'752': [1, 577990, 0],
                   u'756': [1, 903074, 0],
                   u'76': [1, 2733763, 0],
                   u'764': [1, 857348, 0],
                   u'784': [1, 564929, 0],
                   u'792': [1, 979507, 0],
                   u'804': [8, 1073943, 1],
                   u'818': [1, 463162, 0],
                   u'826': [1, 2062694, 0],
                   u'840': [1, 5142062, 0],
                   u'862': [1, 724854, 0]},
 u'Description': u'A social utility that connects people, to keep up with friends, upload photos, share links and videos.',
 u'Engagments': [{u'Bounce': [0.18813037420762707, 0.04348134904172363],
                  u'Month': 9,
                  u'PPV': [21.312597646825566, 0.034059623863791355],
                  u'Reach': [0.3236483914825198, 0.012621437484750864],
                  u'Time': [1225.8536260294338, 0.0009026673459306966],
                  u'Year': 2012},
                 {u'Bounce': [0.17672838267013638, -0.060606861520974054],
                  u'Month': 10,
                  u'PPV': [25.612224490959978, 0.20174109770119109],
                  u'Reach': [0.3132553630508028, -0.03211209666178205],
                  u'Time': [1308.5613956266043, 0.0674695313053506],
                  u'Year': 2012},
                 {u'Bounce': [0.186024790640559, 0.052602801145837264],
                  u'Month': 11,
                  u'PPV': [24.020971463806184, -0.06212865374951859],
                  u'Reach': [0.33350274816471975, 0.06463539815161368],
                  u'Time': [1300.8263833937028, -0.005911080869994256],
                  u'Year': 2012},
                 {u'Bounce': [0.18107629094748873, -0.02660129155920865],
                  u'Month': 12,
                  u'PPV': [24.916914500937356, 0.03729836815638965],
                  u'Reach': [0.3244161087234065, -0.027246070658540122],
                  u'Time': [1331.3137947173564, 0.023436956470790138],
                  u'Year': 2012},
                 {u'Bounce': [0.18097482510209897, -0.0005603485959361221],
                  u'Month': 1,
                  u'PPV': [25.52485794831804, 0.02439882543875216],
                  u'Reach': [0.2999822245222873, -0.07531649490917003],
                  u'Time': [1334.5042854365543, 0.0023964979044441836],
                  u'Year': 2013},
                 {u'Bounce': [0.18673378186827794, 0.03182186673162968],
                  u'Month': 2,
                  u'PPV': [23.201378273544368, -0.09102811382841713],
                  u'Reach': [0.2842911869016958, -0.05230655798215711],
                  u'Time': [1281.8427161473487, -0.03946152130337932],
                  u'Year': 2013}],
 u'GlobalRank': [1, 28115594, 0],
 u'RedirectUrl': u'facebook.com',
 u'Title': u'Facebook',
 u'TrafficReach': [0.3236447516162034,
                   0.3238506691231212,
                   0.3247648143721332,
                   0.31948943452696626,
                   0.310612833573507,
                   0.3086742084043239,
                   0.3066650958404128,
                   0.3133412877265817,
                   0.3355154609011924,
                   0.3260064922555041,
                   0.3339616481060937,
                   0.3399959232708455,
                   0.33711315799626795,
                   0.32152719433964483,
                   0.31986157880865085,
                   0.32069766148623413,
                   0.3306823871380894,
                   0.32266565637788247,
                   0.2903477786960325,
                   0.29286953998372667,
                   0.29969130766646174,
                   0.3071060984450904,
                   0.28517166164955293,
                   0.29038329556338477,
                   0.2845053957123595],
 u'TrafficReachEnd': 1362096000,
 u'TrafficReachStart': 1346457600,
 u'TrafficSources': {u'Direct': 0.6014880950132592,
                     u'Mail': 0.018352638254343783,
                     u'Paid Referrals': 0.0010665044954870533,
                     u'Referrals': 0.24273597651387802,
                     u'Search': 0.12679771428369516,
                     u'Social': 0.009559071439336665}}
```

If your value definition spans multiple lines, we can use the [`JSONDecoder.raw_decode()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode) to make parsing that information out a little easier:

```
import json

script_rest = scripttag.string.split('Sw.preloadedData["overview"]', 1)[1].lstrip(' =')
decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
data, _ = decoder.raw_decode(script_rest)
```

The `raw_decode()` call parses JSON even if there is trailing data, so it'll try and find a full JSON object starting right past the `=` following the `Sw.preloadedData["overview"]` text.

Comment: This, of course, will only work if all json data definitions are in a single line. The OP will have to elaborate it a bit - forgoing line processing and scanning up to the next, unquoted, ";"  to get it to work with the data in the case of more than one line.

Comment: @jsbueno: We can also use the `raw_parse` option; I'll update.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
import re, json
jsondata = json.loads(re.search(r'Sw\.preloadedData\["overview"\] = (.*)', data).group(1).rstrip(';'))
```